# How to process .csv for time series classification

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series

I  was wondering how to handle the recorded time series data to feed it into a RNN.

I want to take the data of 16 time steps and the labels of 15 to make the RNN classify the 16th time step(if that makes any sense). By using every third entry for the batch I can cover about 3 Seconds of data with a reasonable amount of entries per second.

[Here is a smaller .csv of the recorded data.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O_ygyzCaLdv7w8bKej8jbg_a9wfEgbzj/view?usp=sharing) The Columns "Time" and "Mayday" are just for reference to make sure that everything is labeled correctly and can therefore be dropped.
[This is what my data looks like after dropping the unrelated columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJmRb.png)

[Here is what I have tried so far in google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/160R8pYYMihS4nhLlsntNZCp6w-0hjjWD?usp=sharing)
unfortunately this approach doesnt work and I get an "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'" when calling model.fit.

Alternatively I have also tried this:

```
data = pd.read_csv("slim.csv", sep=",")
data.drop(['Time', 'Mayday'], axis=1)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
```

But from there on out I am not sure how to handle the data to get the desired result as calling tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array() on dataset terminates with the error message

```
'TensorSliceDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is fine. The problem is that `train_target` and `test_target` are returning tuples, since as the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/timeseries_dataset_from_array) state:

> Returns a tf.data.Dataset instance. If targets was passed, the dataset
> yields tuple (batch_of_sequences, batch_of_targets). If not, the
> dataset yields only batch_of_sequences.

Since you are only interested in the targets in this case, you can run:

```
data_set = tf.data.Dataset.zip( (train_input ,train_target.map(lambda x, y: y)))
test_set = tf.data.Dataset.zip( (test_input ,test_target.map(lambda x, y: y)))
```

But note that this will still not work, because your targets have the shape `(32, 11)` and your model's output shape is `(32, 3)`. So you should ask yourself what exactly you are trying to achieve.

**Update 1**

Try:

```
import tensorflow as tf

data = pd.read_csv("slim.csv", sep=",")
data = data.drop(['Time', 'Mayday'], axis=1)

window_size = 16
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data.values)).window(window_size, shift=3, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(window_size)).batch(32)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: (x[:, :, :-1], x[:, 15, -1]))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.GRU(input_shape=(None, 8), units= 128),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='tanh'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(dataset, epochs=5)
```

Comment: In the end the network should choose one of the three classes for classification. Is there any sensible way to fix the shape?

Comment: Sure but the question is what exactly you want to do?

Comment: This is a University Project where a car drives along in a track in a simulation environment and the Neural Network should look at the metrics of the last 3 seconds to classify if its driving normally or if something anomalous is happening. 
For this task no Anomaly Detection algorithms should be used.
Was this the information you are looking for? 
I am sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Ok, so actually you just want to extract the label after every `n` timesteps right?

Comment: Yes.
I want to classify the Label of the current metric based on the current and past seconds and to make the most of my data I want to slide trough it.

Later on the Network should recieve the data live while the simulation is running, but for now I just want to get it running on the recorded data
Do I only need to use the last label as Target then and dont need the labels of the other 15 time steps?

Comment: Ok, have you maybe looked at using `tf.data.Dataset.window`?

Comment: dataset.window appeared to me to predict the future label of the time step n+1 based on current data n. But I want to classify the current label n of the current data n. Did I misunderstand it?